# Why should I use garlic making roasted potatoes?

Tags: food-science, garlic

A recipe of roasted potatoes calls for some garlic to be put in the oven with potatoes that are covered with salt and black/red pepper and rosemary. I don't understand what's the role of garlic here, could someone explain?

Comment: The flavour of roasted garlic goes really well with roasted potatos. Are you looking for something deeper?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod: Do you mean we eat them afterwards? Since the recipe says put them aside

Comment: That wasn't clear from your initial post! Maybe if you shared the recipe, we could give you a better answer.

Comment: A better question is, why *wouldn't* you use garlic when making roasted potatoes?

Comment: @logophobe I was just typing exactly that. I don't know why your recipe wouldn't serve the garlic. I'd serve it anyway, with the potatoes. You may want to cut it into smaller pieces, you may not want to use all of it (that's up to your personal taste), but roasted garlic is *lovely* with potatoes. The author of the recipe isn't watching you plate. If you do have garlic left over, you can use it a gazillion ways, including spread on toast.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Could be for appearances.  If it's a fairly long roast, the recipe might call for the cloves to be left whole or crushed to let the flavor subtly infuse without breaking down completely.  Finely chopping the garlic might make it burn, turn to little mushy bits, or produce a really strong flavor.  And as much as I like garlic, eating a whole clove is a bit much.  But I agree completely - recipes are guidelines, not laws!  Do whatever you want with the garlic.  You can just wave it over the pan a couple times if that's your thing.

Comment: @logophobe I meant chopping up the garlic after roasting. Chopped garlic will burn if roasted with potatoes, whole cloves are usually fine. Note to OP: If you're at all unsure, toss the whole cloves of garlic with some oil and give the potatoes a head start. If you lightly crush the cloves, definitely give the potatoes a few minutes of a head start. Burnt garlic is nasty.

Answer (score 7):

I assume the recipe says to put the garlic in the pan with the potatoes, not just in the oven with them, in which case the garlic will flavour the fat you are roasting the potatoes in, and so will subtly flavour the potatoes themselves.

Comment: And roasted garlic is sweet and delicious.